# take photo image works in debug mode but not when run

Tags: java, android

I am developing using a nexus 7 as a real device.

I have just split up a working app into fragments to make the layouts cleaner, all elements are working except the photo processing.

The photo is taken and saved in the Camera folder with the filename photoFile.

I have tried displaying the image using bitmapfactory and drawable image - code segments below

```
    personImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagePerson);


                    String pFile = photoFile.toString();                        
//                      Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pFile);
//                      personImage.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pFile);
                    personImage.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The weird thing is it works in debug mode - I breakpoint at the String pfile then step through - and the image displays properly. When I run it not in debug it doesn't display anything. It is almost like there is a timing issue, there isn't enough time to process the image.

I have wasted too long fiddling with this, trying anything I can find on SO. Please help!

Comment: is there any error shows in logcat?? or just put some debug log to find out which line break this whole thing. after that put your latest code and logcat here to get more idea about your question.

Comment: I just found the problem. It was tied up with the startActivityForResult and onActivityResult when taking the photo. I am not sure exactly how I fixed it, but it was around tying up the onActivityResult through the parent activity - I didn't realise you had to do that. I had getActivity().startActivity in the fragment which seemed to work in debug mode but in run mode just did nothing, no errors. Which is why it was weird. However I went through SO in a different search and found the correct way to handle it, so thanks again SO. And thanks Anil for looking at it.